# A drawing in Murre's notes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was looking at Murre's notes on the fundamental group of a scheme and came across the following picture, which I find a bit confusing. If someone understands the identification that is supposed to happen, I would be glad to get a clearer description of what is going on.

The full quote includes the following text:

> [...] we may take two copies $\tilde C$ and $\tilde C'$ of the
>   normalisation of $C$ and fuse them together is such a way that the
>   points $a,b$ on $\tilde C$ are identified with the points $b',a'$ on
>   $\tilde C'$. We then get a connected but reducible variety $X$ and the
>   morphism $p$ defined in the obvious manner is surely étale.

[image: picture from 3.2]

Comment: A clearer picture of the same construction is given in Figure 12, Exercise III.10.6 on p. 276 of Hartshorne.

Comment: @Nefertiti thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, answering my own question. The user Nefertiti pointed in the comments to the following picture in Hartshorne, and it seems indeed to be a clearer version of the same idea.

[image]